# PostgreSQL Function Error 42883 on one site, not on other

Tags: postgresql, function

We have a staging site where our custom function works just fine. After copying the function to another site (Using Navicat's Structure Sync), the same function returns a 42883: function... does not exist error

We've checked the parameters to make sure they match, checked the Owner rights, and made sure the Types were the same.

Any ideas on what else to look for?

Thanks.

Comment: Compare the `search_path` on both.

Comment: search_path is the same on both sites.